# Rails view error "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" error after upgrading Ruby to 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

Running Rails 2.3.9 and just upgraded to Ruby 1.9.2p0. I have been putting:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

in a bunch of my .rb files where ever "£" character is used, and this seems to be working. But i just got my first view error:

```
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCI
```

for this line of code:

```
<%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => "£", :precision => 0) %>
```

I don't think its a coincidence that the "£" character is involved again. Any ideas on how to solve this please?

Thanks

Comment: "Ugly" solution: replace £ with \x00A3. Define `gbp_symbol = "\x00A3"` and use that instead of £.

Comment: Thanks Zabba, but this just renders "A" instead of "£"

Comment: This may have to do with encodings of read IO objects, not the source files (which you have solved with the 'magic comment'). See http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded to Ruby version 1.8.7

Comment: *facepalm* 

Try [encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode).